# Running protractor config results 'This webpage is not available'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to test protractor on a vanilla.js app and when I run `protractor basicConf.js`

I am getting below error :

> This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is my test:

```
describe('foo', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('index.html');
  });

  it('should return the same result as browser.findElement', function() {


    $('#newItem').sendKeys('sdg');
    element('#addBtn').click().then(function(){

    });

  });

})
```

And my protractor config:

```
// The main suite of Protractor tests.
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
  specs: [
    'spec.js'
  ],

  // Exclude patterns are relative to this directory.
  exclude: [
    'basic/exclude*.js'
  ],


  capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + ( '8082'),

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    realtimeFailure: true
  },

  params: {
    login: {
      user: 'Jane',
      password: '1234'
    }
  }
};
```

Any ideas what I need to do to start fixing this?

I have run both:

protactor `npm install -g protractor` 
 webdriver `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: what version of chrome browser are you using? Also can you mention the webdriver, protractor and jasmine versions?

Comment: v  45.0.2454.85 (64-bit), protractor 2.2. I'm not using jasmine as far as I know. webdriver 2.45.1

Comment: As far as i can understand your code seems fine. Can you try to replace your baseUrl and see if it helps - `baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + '8082',` ?

Comment: thanks but no effect

Answer (score 0):

Error connection gets refused if either the webdriver server isn't started or there is a configuration compatibility issue with your protractor and browser. Looking at your config file and config data, there is no such issue. However, you should start your webdriver before running your tests. Open a command prompt in windows or terminal in mac and then run the following command to start the selenium webdriver -

```
webdriver-manager start
```

Later run your protractor scripts with the command that you already have. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you paste complete error logs here to check the problem @SuperUberDuper ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your test I believe the issue originates from the address that you are passing to the browser.get() function. You'll want to either reference the baseUrl you setup in the config file and append the "index.html" piece in your test or adjust the baseUrl and reference that in your beforeEach function. Try one of the following:

```
...
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8082',
...

browser.get(browser.baseUrl + '/index.html');
```

or

```
...
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8082/',
...

browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
```

or

```
browser.get('http://localhost:8082/index.html');
```

---

Also you could try this:

```
...
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8082/index.html');
...

browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
```